# In undo history, how to separate abbrev expansion from self-insert?

Tags: undo, abbrev

Very occasionally, hit `SPC` during regular typing and get an unexpected abbrev expansion. What I usually do in this case is `undo` (which reverts the expansion and the inserted space) and then manually `C-q SPC` to add the space again.

It would be really useful if, when I hit `undo`, only the expansion would get reverted, but the space would stay. Then, hitting `undo` a second time could revert the space insertion too. This is what you usually see in editors with auto-correction features (the first undo affects the correction, the second affects the space you typed).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You need `undo-boundary`.

For [example](https://github.com/abo-abo/abel):

```
(defun abel-expand ()
  "Expand the abbrev before point."
  (when (= (length (this-command-keys-vector)) 1)
    (insert-char (aref (this-command-keys-vector) 0))
    (undo-boundary)
    (backward-delete-char 1))
  (unless (memq (aref (this-command-keys-vector) 0) '(?- ?+ ?/ ?_))
    (when (looking-at "[])} ]")
      (let ((pt (point)))
        (skip-chars-backward "[[:alnum:]]")
        (let* ((name (buffer-substring-no-properties (point) pt))
               (body (gethash name abel--table)))
          (delete-region (point) pt)
          (insert body))))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the function. Any idea how I can incorporate this into regular abbrevs?

Comment: Nope, I have no idea how regular abbrevs work.